# Does the latest version of SquishIt still have the issues with JavaScript closures

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, squishit

While doing some analysis on the usage details for the SquishIt framework, I came across a link as mentioned below:

https://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/tag/squishit/

which describes that SquishIt is having some problems with getting to work with JavaScript closures.

I am currently using the latest version :0.9.3.0 of SquishIt.Mvc. Can anyone help me to know whether this version has still the issues while working with JavaScript closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any issues at this time (was not aware of any in 2010 either however).  It seems like any issues with closures are probably really issues with the minification library used, or files incorrectly terminated.  At some point in the last couple years I think we did start adding semicolons between concatenated files if not present to deal with the latter.  If you do find any I would love to hear about them.